# Logging values inside a gesture event listener in React Native Reanimated

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated-v2

I have a Gesture Pan handler that I'd like to log the values of into the console as I move it around. I wanted to know if there was a better way apart from using `RunOnJS` to console.log values out, or if there is a better practise to follow when logging such values.

```
const gesture = Gesture.Pan()
        .onStart((event) => {
            // I want to log values from these events. Attributes such as event.translationY
        })
        .onUpdate((event) => {
            // I want to log values from these events. Attributes such as event.translationY
        })
```